# Why could be the same code in oracle stored java procedure slower than in regular java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

I'm developing a stored java procedure that is called inside other PL/SQL procedure. In the JAVA code I need to select ~500 columns that returns ~5000 rows and process the data (generate XML with StAX to BLOB with size ~8 MB). The processing has just linear complexity and there are no time or memory expensive operations.

When I run the code on my desktop and connect to remote DB server, it runs in ~3 seconds. When I deploy the program to DB as stored Java procedure, it runs in ~14 seconds.

I don't understand why. I would expect that the code runs on the database with internal JDBC driver faster as there are no data roundtrips. The only change I make in the code is the way I get connection.

The interesting thing is that the code on Oracle DB consumes significantly less memory, but when I got increased memory limits, it didn't help.

Any ideas how where could be the problem?

What I can not do is:

- use standard DB-XML mapping tools as it is not just simple conversion, but there is some business logic behind it
- rewrite the algorithm to pure PL/SQL as there are lot of object-oriented features used and it would be too hard to write and maintain it procedurally
- place the code to application server as it is just one step of data-processing in PL/SQL

Comment: have you tried to [profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_profil.htm) your pl/sql code?

Comment: Which JVM versions on either side? Heap size settings? Have you tried to call the java stored procedure directly (= without PL/SQL)?

Comment: The time ~14 seconds is not the time of the whole procedure, it's just time of the java code behind one call in PL/SQL. From the Java code I don't call any PL/SQL procedures, just one big select with readonly forward-only resultset. The select is done in ~250 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities not excluded by the information you have posted: faster desktop processor and/or DB server under higher load.

Comment: +1: V. good basic points to check. I'd be interested in knowing what the server CPU is, as the recent trend in multicore processors has left us with more but relatively weak cores.